# JSON from URL not being printed android

Tags: android, json, urlconnection

So I have a url that I get json from, it seems like everything is okay (I get 200 response code back), however, when I try to print the whole json, it prints

> I/System.out﹕ java.io.BufferedInputStream@6cf1c21

Code below:

```
 URL url = "myurl.com";
    try {
        url = new URL("url");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        System.out.println("Response Code: " + conn.getResponseCode());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(in.toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I/System.out﹕ java.io.BufferedInputStream@6cf1c21` is the output of the default `toString()` implementation of the `Object` class. You should read pass the stream to a reader, like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        out.append(line);
}
System.out.println(out.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you.  Worked like a charm.  Now the part of the actual parsing, which might cause more questions :).

Comment: Glad I could help you out! Good luck with that! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

It's your last line!

Instead of

```
System.out.println(in.toString());
```

try

```
String s = " ";

while(in.ready()){
    s += in.readLine();
}

in.close();
System.out.println(s);
```